# Want a Condition for This Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, redirect

Any Javascript expert could help me here.

i am a template developer and i use this script to show my footer link in every free template created by me. and when someone trying to remove footer link their site redirected to my site **example.com**...

But What

some users download my template and hide my footer link with this CSS property: **visibility:hidden**

script is here that i use in template bottom,

abc

And some users add **visibility:hidden** to footer link in template like this. check in here.

```
<a id="credit" href="http://www.example.com"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com/">abc</a></a>
```

So, my point is here, that what should add in **first script**, so that if someone add **visibility:hidden** and then it should redirected to my official site example.com

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If someone wants to remove the link to your page from the template then this person will always be able to do so.

Comment: One way around is to make a trick. Generate random id for your div to be appended in footer and obfuscate your script code, so that some might find it difficult to understand.

Comment: Just as a note to the comment of @ParkashKumar. This might help for the _bad guys_. But if I would be about to use a free template with a copyright/origin information, then I would only use it if I could review the exiting code. Having only a obfuscated code of a not well known company/source is or should normally be  reason not to use that template/code a site.

Comment: The question here is that OP don't want the link to be removed from the footer. Its bit tricky and will require a trick to handle it as well. It might smell like bad guys. But in my sense it is somewhat security trick. OP has objected nothing about the usability of templates. So that is not the topic to be discussed, I think.

Comment: @ParkashKumar sure, this should not be offensive against your comment. I just added you that you will know that you are mentioned. But because the OP wants that his free templates are used / spread, he should also keep in mind that adding obfuscated code might be a reason that people wont use his free template. The more you try to _protect_ against the _bad guys_  removing the copyright/source info, the more problematic it will be for the good people. So yes my comment might be off-topic, but I believe its still worth to mention.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#myContent').css('visibility') === 'hidden')
    window.location('http://wherever');
```

This?

Edit: Of course, @t.niese is right and this is really an exercise in futility.

Comment: Hi, widget, the script is not working....i tried several times....for better understanding i post here, check it and do answer of that if possible..          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520389/i-want-a-very-simple-javascript

Answer (score 0):

What if you detect style change event on your element?

[MutationObservers - Is this useful for you?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver)

[MutationEvents - also please take look at this](http://engineering.silk.co/post/31921750832/mutation-events-what-happens?)

You could also try to obfuscate your code and maybe use javascript singleton function pattern.

Comment: We have visited [http://www.templatezy.com/](http://www.templatezy.com/) Maybe you could provide us with information about template format and how they are processed and integrated into webpage?